# Define command to remove header on specific pages

Tags: fancyhdr

More concretely, I want to define a command that removes the header (fancyhdr) only on the first page of a section. When I use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` it clears the header also on the following pages of the section and I want to remove the header only on the first page of a section.

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}`

Comment: I only want to remove the header, but leave the footer, so this doesn't work for me

Comment: I picked plain as that has empty head and just a page number in foot but use any page style, define  suitable one using fancyhdr or possibly simpler use fancyhdr to redefine the plain style to have a suitable foot

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202640/161015